# How to 'ungroup' aggregated data to rows?

Tags: sql, impala

I have a table with a similar schema:

```
basket_id | product | volume
101       | apple   | 3
102       | apple   | 2
102       | orange  | 2
```

I am trying to 'ungroup' or 'deaggregate' the table to the following.

Desired output:

```
basket_id | product | volume
101       | apple   | 1
101       | apple   | 1
101       | apple   | 1
102       | apple   | 1
102       | apple   | 1
102       | orange  | 1
102       | orange  | 1
```

I have tried some unions and case statements but none are giving me the desired result without much effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you need a sequence number.  If your table is big enough (as in your case), you can use it directly:

```
with n as (
      select row_number() over (order by basket_id) as n
      from t
     ) t
select t.basket_id, t.product, 1 as volume
from t join
     n
     on n.n <= t.volume;
```

If the table is not big enough, you might have a numbers table or larger table lurking around.  Otherwise, you can construct one with `join`s.

Answer (score 0):

On way to solve it is to generate a list of numbers and then join it:

```
select basket_id, product, 1
from mytable t
inner join (
    select 1 n union all select 2 union all select 3
) x on t.volume <= x.n
```

You can expand the `unioned` subquery with more numbers as needed.